# Making a Button in mapinfo with conditional function

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have following code  :

```
Sub create_ButtonFromVendor
      Dim i As Integer
      i=1
      Create ButtonPad "allVendor"  As
        ToggleButton
        Icon MI_ICON_ZOOM_QUESTION
          Calling get_Vendor
          HelpMsg vendors(i)
        Show
       For i = 2 TO Ubound(vendors)
          Alter ButtonPad "allVendor" Add
          ToggleButton
          Icon MI_ICON_ZOOM_QUESTION
          Calling vendor_ButtonAction(vendors(i))
          HelpMsg vendors(i)
        Show
      Next
    End Sub
```

It is small sub procedure. Here I wanted to create multiple buttons with different function in a loop. How would I add function in a loop? In the code I added above does not work as handler must be sub procedure without parameter.

Comment: Just tested it - doesn't work. Gives the following error message: Commandinfo: Argument 2 out of range. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Our protocols can take a little getting used to so I hope you don't mind me pointing out that you have placed what looks like a comment in the area reserved for directly providing an Answer to the Question posed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would let the buttons call the same subprecedure ...

```
For i = 2 To Ubound(vendors)
    Alter ButtonPad "allVendor" Add
       ToggleButton
          ID 1000 + i
          Icon MI_ICON_ZOOM_QUESTION
          Calling vendor_ButtonAction
          HelpMsg vendors(i)
Next
```

and in the subprocedure use CommandInfo() to figure out what button the user clicked on ...

```
Sub vendor_ButtonAction
   Dim nVendorIndex As Integer

   nVendorIndex = (CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_TOOLBTN) - 1000)

   Note "You clicked on vendor " & vendors(nVendorIndex)

End Sub
```

I have not tested the code, so I can not guarantee that it works, but I'm sure you get the idea